# How to perform a p2 Install programmatically

Tags: java, p2

I would like to use p2 to perform an installation through code, much as the p2 Director does it, but I can't find the API. Could someone please point me to a good place to start looking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a good starting point in the class **DirectorApplication**, which is part of the plug-in **org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director.app**.

Answer (score 0):

I use a script to perform this operation. There you can define special variables in case you need them. A script which is passed to ruby and run. You should be able to do the same in JAVA. Depends though how platform-independent should it be.

An idea for the API would be to look how the [Marketplace Client](http://download.eclipse.org/mpc/kepler/) plugin does the installation of the Marketplace plugins.

Comment: Hi Mirca, thanks for yor input. That is the way we are handling it at the moment. Unfortunately our costumer isn't satisfied with this solution, since you can't display a proper progress indicator and you can't display proper error messages when something goes wrong.